# How to reduce space between header and text?

Tags: header-footer

I m using mdframed as header. Now i want to reduce the space between header and first line on page. How can i reduce the space?

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{array,multirow}
 \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
 \usepackage{fancyhdr}
 \usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
 \usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=1cm, right=1cm]{geometry}
 \pagestyle{fancy}
 \fancyhf{} % sets both header and footer to nothing 
 \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
 \fancyfoot{}
 \begin{document}

 \arrayrulecolor{white}


 \definecolor{textcol}{rgb}{.118, .565, 1.00}   


 \fancyhead[C]{% 
 \begin{mdframed}[linecolor=blue!60,roundcorner=3pt] 
 \parbox[t]{0.333\textwidth}{\raggedright XXX }% 
 \parbox[t]{0.333\textwidth}{\centering \thepage}%  
 \parbox[t]{0.333\textwidth}{\raggedleft YYY} 
 \end{mdframed}% 
} 

Some text 

\end{document}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.

While solving problems is fun, setting them up is not. Then those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with reducing `headsep` using `geometry` package.

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{array,multirow}
 \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
 \usepackage{fancyhdr}
 \usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
 \usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=1cm, right=1cm,headsep=4pt]{geometry}  %% adjust here
 \pagestyle{fancy}
 \fancyhf{} % sets both header and footer to nothing 
 \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
 \fancyfoot{}
 \begin{document}

 \arrayrulecolor{white}


 \definecolor{textcol}{rgb}{.118, .565, 1.00}   


 \fancyhead[C]{% 
 \begin{mdframed}[linecolor=blue!60,roundcorner=3pt] 
 \parbox[t]{0.333\textwidth}{\raggedright XXX }% 
 \parbox[t]{0.333\textwidth}{\centering \thepage}%  
 \parbox[t]{0.333\textwidth}{\raggedleft YYY} 
 \end{mdframed}% 
} 

Some text 

\end{document}
```

However, reducing `headsep` will spoil the consistency and elegance.

[image]